Have a different ringtone for each person in an RCS chat?
I have a OnePlus 12 on Android 14, and a RCS chat in Google Messages with about a half dozen people that is very active. Currently, when someone sends a messages in that chat, it plays a custom ringtone that I set up. However, this has a problem: if I am not looking at my phone and I hear the notification sound, I cannot tell at a(n auditory) glance who just sent a message.
Is there a way to set up individual ringtones based on sender in an RCS chat? (I already know how to do this on a per-chat basis: Chat > triple dots > Group Details > Notifications > Ringtone. I am asking about doing this on a per-person basis in a single chat.)

If I'm not mistaken, try checking the per-Conversation entry on the Android Notification settings for Google Messages.
